# is there a max number of parameters that can be used in url mapping?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

I'm working on a catalog type program and need to track bread-crumbs during browsing and searching while creating SEO friendly URL's.  I have Categories that can go 5 levels deep, its rare, but could happen.  I think I'm running into a limitation and cannot find anything that address how many parameters can be used for mapping.

my map looks like this:

```
routes.MapRout(
     "CategoryPath",
     "products/{cat1}/{cat2}/{cat3}/{cat4}/{cat5}",
     new { controller = "CategoryPath",
          action = "Index", 
          cat1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
          cat2 = UrlParameter.Optional,
          cat3 = UrlParameter.Optional,
          cat4 = UrlParameter.Optional,
          cat5 = UrlParameter.Optional
     });
```

And my links are created like this:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "CategoryPath", new { cat1 = row.Title, })
@Url.Action("Index", "CategoryPath", new { cat1 = row.Title, cat2 = subrow.Title })
```

So when the links are rendered (using only up to cat4) it renders correctly as

```
 ~/products/pruductCategory1
```

and 
 `~/products/productCategory1/productCategory2` respectively.

However, once I add cat5 they render this way

```
~/CategoryPath?cat1=productCategory1
```

and

```
~/products/productCategory1/productCategory2
```

If anyone knows of this limitation or a possible workaround I'd appreciate it.

Comment: There is a max number of characters for the url, I think. But your problem here is that you have 5 Optional parameters.  You can only have one per route.

Comment: Only the last parameter of a route can be optional. Your route declaration doesn't make sense. `cat1`, `cat2`, `cat3` and `cat4` cannot be optional if you want to use such url pattern. Otherwise the routing engine will never be able to disambiguate your urls.

Comment: If only one parameter can be optional, do I need to place the others ad cat1 = "" for the previous ones? It doesn't seem to influence it if I do, I still get the wrong format

Comment: No, you don't need to place them as empty. You need to give them a value. Like this `cat1="some value for cat1", cat2="some value for cat 2"` and so on...

Comment: ok, so if I understand what your saying I need to take a different approach to this since the levels of the catalog are dynamically created by the end user and may change. So I may need to need to create a map that would compile the parent levels into one parameter and the current level in a separate parameter. Which would eventually allow for deeper levels if the user so desired